# TypeError: 'Pyre' object is not subscriptable (I'm getting this error even though it was never there before)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit, pyrebase

I started working with Pyrebase recently and it's been going smoothly. However, today, I started getting an error from an update statement that I wasn't getting before.

I didn't change anything in the code.

The statement triggering the TypeError is:

```
db.child("teams").child(x['creatorId']).update({'player01':creator_name,'player02':str(request)})
```

`'creatorId'` is a key from a dictionary I've saved in a JSON file. In a previous step, I ran a loop to get the value of `creatorId`, which is what I'm using here.

`creator_name` is a discord username (username#discriminator):

```
creator = bot.get_user(x['creatorId'])
creator_name = creator.name + "#" + creator.discriminator
```

`request` is also a discord username: `request = bot.get_user(payload.user_id)`. I'm using `str()` here because it doesn't let me update Firebase with a Member object, and therefore, I have to turn `request` (which is a Discord username) into a string.

The error is:
`TypeError: 'Pyre' object is not subscriptable`

Also, I'm running the code on Repl.it, and a few times before, Repl.it showed me errors where none were there, so that may also be a cause. But that usually solved itself when I refreshed the page. This error does not solve itself like that.

Any and all help is appreciated. Please let me know if I've forgotten any important details.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out.

What I did was this:

I created a new variable to store `x['CreatorId']`:

```
creator_id = x['creatorId']
```

Afterwards, I replaced the `x['creatorId']` in the update statement with the new variable. So, the new code looks like this:

```
db.child('teams').child(creator_id).update({'player01':creator_name,'player02':str(request)})
```